Problema al hacer un Laravel PHP return response despues de una consultra
Tengo una base de datos en la que uno de los modelos se llama "entrades", con un campo llamado "correu". Estoy haciendo una funcion de ruta en la que quiero que me retorne en formato JSON los objetos de esa tabla con un campo "correu" concreto. Estoy usando Laravel v10.40.0 (PHP v8.1.10).
El modelo de "entrades" es este.
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class entrades extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'nom',
        'correu',
        'data_compra',
        'esdeveniment_id'
    ];

    public function esdeveniments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(esdeveniments::class);
    }
} 

Esta es la funcion que tengo en el archivo de rutas.
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/entrades/compres/{correu}', function ($correu) {
    $entradesComprades = entrades::Where('correu', $correu);
    return response($entradesComprades);
});

Al hacer una peticion GET con el postman, me da el error

TypeError: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given, called in C:\laragon\www\api-tokens\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php on line 72 in file C:\laragon\www\api-tokens\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php on line 449

Como podria realizar la funcion para que me devolviera los objetos? En el controlador de "entrades" tengo la funcion show() de esta forma, devolviendome una lista como en la imagen, en formato json, hay alguna forma de que lo devuelva asi?
 public function index()
    {
        $entrades = entrades::paginate(10);
        return response($entrades);
    }



Creo que si devuelves $entrades->items() te vale

Buenas. Consegui arreglarlo cambiando el
$entradesComprades = entrades::Where('correu', $correu); por
$entradesComprades = entrades::where('correu', '=', $correu)->paginate(15);

Perfecto, si a una query de laravel no la terminas con : first(),get(),paginate(),take()... no lanzara la consulta y no te dara ningun resultado

@RogerOrtiz marca la pregunta como resuelta.

No puedo  marcarlo como resuelto, creo que necesito tener una respuesta como tal en la pregunta para ello.

El problema se pudo arreglar cambiando el
$entradesComprades = entrades::Where('correu', $correu);

por
$entradesComprades = entrades::where('correu', '=', $correu)->paginate(15);

